# can we have a main() in an interface and different implementations for main() in the classes that implement this interface?

Tags: java, program-entry-point, overriding

I know that main() can be overloaded in a class with the compiler always taking the one with `String[] args` as arguments as the main method from where the execution starts. But is it possible to declare the same

```
main(String args[]) in an interface and implement it in different classes differently?
```

For example,

```
package test;
interface test
{
    public void main(String args[]);
    public void display();
}



package test;
class Testclass1 implements test
{
   public void display()
   {
       System.out.println("hello");
    }
   public static void main(String[] args)
   {
       test t;
       t.display();
    }
}


package temp;
import test.*;
abstract class Testclass2 implements test
{
   public static void main(String args[])
   {
       System.out.println("TESTING");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

No you cannot, because `main` has to be static in order to be used as an entry point, and Interfaces dont allow the use of static, until `Java 7`.

Yes you can run a `psvm` in an interface, if you're working in `Java 8`. Because static methods are allowed in an interface starting from Java 8.

But of course, you cannot override the `main` method, since `psvm` is a static method.

Comment: And yet there are more answers. ;)

Comment: `psvm` = public static void main

Answer (score 13):

With Java-8 you can have main method defined inside the interface, Below code will work in Java-8.

```
public interface TestInterfaces {
    public static void main(String[] a){    
        System.out.println("I am a static main method inside Inteface !!");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There are two answers for your question.

1. First of all, you can't have `static` methods in an `Interface`
2. Yes you can overload `main()` method, but when you launch your class, only the
   `public static void main(String args[]){}` method will be treated as an entry point.

For example

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("entry point)");
    }

    public static void main(String arg1) {
        System.out.println("overload2");
    }

    public static void main(String arg1, String arg2) {
        System.out.println("overload3");
    }
}
```

When you launch the above class, the out will be "`entry point`"

Comment: +1 for "*you can't have `static` methods in an `Interface`*", since this is the only answer to this question.

Comment: You can in Java 8, @Lion

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure But You can have multiple main methods in **multiple classes (not the same class)**.
We start the program with the name of the class whose main method we want to run. So after that JVM will look for main method in that class only. So there should not be any problem.

I am not sure so please let me know if I am wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You can create you own startup mechanism, but I am not sure why you would want to.

```
public class RunTests {
    public static void main(String... args) throws ClassNotFoundException {
        List<Class> classes = new ArrayList<Class>();
        try {
            for (String arg : args) {
                classes.add(Class.forName(arg));
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            if (classes.isEmpty())
                throw e;
        }
        String[] remainingArgs = Arrays.asList(args).subList(classes.size(), args.length).toArray(new String[0]);
        for(Class clazz: classes) {
            try {
                Test test = (Test) clazz.newInstance();
                test.main(remainingArgs);
                test.display();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}

interface Test {
    public void main(String... args);
    public void display();
}
```

BTW: You don't have to have a main() method, e.g.

```
class NoMain {
    static {
       System.out.println("Hello World");
       System.exit(0);
    }
}
```

compiles and runs without error.

Answer (score 0):

you declared a main(String[] args) as static in Testclass1,but in interface "test" it is non-static and interface not allow main(String[] args) as static .even if you override main(String[] args) in Testcalss1 as non-static it's not allowed, because main(String args)  is already defined in Testclass1.so you cannot declare main(String[] args) in interface.And u done a one more mistaken is initializing the interface test as t.You cannot do that.

Answer (score 0):

main() is static.so, we cant override static methods.Interfaces allows abstract methods methods & they will be implemented in subclasses.So, abstract methods never be static.finally I concluded that main() is not possible to execute in interfaces.

Answer (score 0):

You can write static main method in Interface in java 8 but you can't override it as it's a static one.

Answer (score 0):

hoping this example would help:

> to access the interface static methods we need to use interface name: from java 1.8

```
interface A {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Interface main method");
    }
}
public class MyClass {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        A.main(new String[]{});
        System.out.println("Main main");
    }
}
```

###### output:

Interface main method

Main main

Answer (score -1):

I think you are missing something. Static methods (like the main method in `Testclass1` and `Testclass2`) cannot override subclass methods.

Comment: Interfaces can't have `static` methods at all !

Comment: Where did I say it could ? Jeez

Comment: you didn't say it couldn't either !

Answer (score -1):

Answer : Yes, we can provide different implementation of main() declared in an interface and classes implementing that interface by overriding method and can overload static main method if defined in an interface.

Some more information regarding interface changes in Java 8.

Prior to Java 8, it was not possible to DEFINE methods inside interface.

But there are changes made to Java 8 with respect to interface where one can DEFINE default and static method inside an interface. Hence below code will work fine without any issue.

```
public interface TestInterfaces {
    public static void main(String[] a){    
        System.out.println("I am a static main method inside Inteface !!");
    }
}
```

For information regarding this features, please refer below link:
http://www.journaldev.com/2752/java-8-interface-changes-static-method-default-method

Answer (score -2):

this is a compiler error. you cant override  a non static interface a static method