# Java 8 : Difference of main method in class and interface and thread creation

Tags: java, java-8

I am going through the tutorial of java 8 and come to know that we can have main method in interface also and it works in same way as it works in class.

so just want to know how it is difference of main method in class and interface.

Interface

```
public interface MainInterface
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        System.out.println("in main interface");
    }
}
```

Class

```
public class MainClass
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        System.out.println("in main class");
    }
}
```

just extending my question

say if we are calling the main method of our class like given below,then only it will create only thread which is of MainInterface

```
public interface MainInterface
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        System.out.println("in main interface");
        MainClass mc = new MainClass();
        String[] s = { "sparsh" };
        mc.main(s);
    }
}
```

Comment: I've never seen a `main` method in an interface in any real project.

Comment: It is technically possible to put the `main` method in an interface and it works the same as in a class, but this is however not a common way to do this in Java - so you should not normally do that.

Comment: @lealceldeiro but you can have with java 8

Comment: @sparsh610 : Just because you can doesn't mean you should.  I'm not sure what the confusion is here.  In general, Java 8 allows interfaces to have static methods.  `main` is a static method, which it so happens the runtime will look for if given the name of the class (or interface) when launching.

Comment: See here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9699247/can-we-have-a-main-in-an-interface-and-different-implementations-for-main-in

Comment: The author probably used `interface` so that the class was not instantiable. It's a mistake, IMO. Firstly because the interface has no methods, and secondly because other classes would be able to implement it. The correct way to solve this is to declare the class as final and give it a private constructor.

Comment: @lealceldeiro I estimate that is 99% because developers have, like, always put main methods in classes; the remaining 1% is because you should only use interfaces to define types (there's an item in *Effective Java* about that), and unless you've got a really good reason to define a main method in something to define type, it's just the wrong place to put it.

Comment: The `main` method is just a normal `static` method. With Java 8 you can add `static` methods to interfaces, so technically you can add the `main()` method too. However I can't think of a clear 'intent' for this to be done, since you need to start your program by instantiating a real class, unless the interface has some default factory method.

Comment: Personally, it looks silly to me and like someone is just trying to find some obscure reason to use every new feature that Java comes out with and that's the best they came up with haha

Comment: I just started the tutorial, so i thought if we can have it , might be there is chance it has some useful feature to use it in interface.but seeing all the comment. i think, it is one of the feature which we are not going to use in nearby future :P

Comment: @JabariDash Well. In Scala, you have the application trait for example. That works similar (even better). To a certain degree, it is tempting to just implement that interface, and voila, something happens. But I guess it would be really hard to get to the level of convenience that the Scala trait gives you in Java.

Comment: One difference is that `public static` is not needed on an interface.